# My compass has stopped working together with Grunt

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

Im using sass and compass together with Grunt to build my project. But suddenly compass has just stopped working. When i run my Grunt i get this error:

"Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
ERROR: Cannot load compass.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue."

The versions are:

compass (0.12.4)
sass (3.2.18)

I have googled ant tried a lot of stuff but none seems to work for me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should consider adding your Gruntfile here.

Comment: Haha, you're totally right here. I got it to work do by simply reinstall ruby, sass, compass and grunt.